# Listings package - the symbol \ isn't colored while rest of the macro is

Tags: listings

I am using the package `listings` for code printing, but I have come across a problem. I usually write down a `lstlisting` environment like this (this is for the LaTeX language):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=latex,caption=Skelet.,label=skelet]
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
```

And specify a style **latex** in the preamble like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{latex}{
language=[LaTeX]TeX,
numbers=left,
commentstyle=\color{red}, 
backgroundcolor=\color{gray},
keywordstyle=\color{red},
identifierstyle=,
tabsize=3
}
```

After compiling the source file I get a beautiful result but for example macros like `\input`, `\usepackage`, `\begin` don't have a sign `\` colored in red. How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT:**

After using command `\ThisULCornerWallPaper` from package `wallpaper` I noticed that the accepted solution isn't working in general...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `texcsstyle` instead of `keywordstyle`; the `*` means that the backslash is colored too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}

\lstdefinestyle{latex}{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!30},
  texcsstyle=*\color{red},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=latex,caption=Skelet.,label=skelet]
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I added usage of typewriter style and no added interletter space (revert it if needed) and a lighter background color.

[image]

Comment: This is a really good solution - Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed that this is not the full solution as the comand `\ThisULCornerWallPaper` from the package `wallpaper` isn't colored corectly (check my edit) when using this method. Are there any solutions?

Comment: @71GA I think that the addition requires more investigation than I'm wanting to do now and possibly would require a big change in the answer. So it's better to ask a new question with a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: I will do this then.